# What is an antiequivalence of two categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Hello everyone, I am a newbie to the category theory. While reading some paper about infinite Galois theory, the 'anti-equivalence' of two categories showed up. Could anyone give me a 'good' explanation what this means? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anti-equivalence of two categories is the same as duality between two categories.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All it means that one of the categories is equivalent to the opposite of the other.

Wikipedia has informative pages on opposites of categories and equivalences
of categories:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_%28category_theory%29 ,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories .